# Swagger iOS client host modification

Tags: objective-c, swagger

I have generated my objective c codes from yaml file through swagger-codegen commandline. Now, I have 2 servers where the same API is available. How can I change the host programmatically?

There is a host property in SWGConfiguration.h. But updating it isn't solving my problem due to the singleton behavior of the generated code. Client keeps calling the old API host.

What is the proper way to change this? In android, host can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own `SWGApiClient` with the `initWithBaseURL` method, and set that when constructing any of your API classes.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Swagger-codegen already generated this code for me. But I have to modify the generated code so that it will create another `SWGApiClient` with new url. If there is another way where url could be changed without creating a new object, it would be great.